# Reducing the size of the partition used by Windows

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, windows, gparted

I want to increase the size allocated for Ubuntu, but for this I need to reduce the size for Windows. Gparted does not allow managing Windows partitions. What to do?

Comment: Do you get any error messages from gparted? Can you include a screenshot of your current partition layout? Please [edit] your post to add this information.

Comment: Please search before asking. There are many articles about resizing partition from Windows. https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-files-winpc/resize-windows-10-system-partition/914938c2-a0f7-4ad0-9730-230ac6fe38ba

Comment: @N0rbert: Every answer on that page discusses gparted. As Sudodus points out Windows tools should be used to shrink Windows partitions.

Answer (score 1):

- Boot into Windows and shrink the Windows partition using Windows tools. Leave the space that is released as unallocated.
- Boot into a live Ubuntu DVD or USB drive.
- Use gparted to create or edit partitions (and use the unallocated drive space).
- If there are still problems for gparted, please reboot instead of shut down Windows. This avoids [semi]hibernating, and the file system will be ready for the linux tools. Later on you can turn of Fast Startup in Windows, which makes it stop semihibernating.